# how to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

how can I detect a locked/unlocked  iOS device using Swift ( like the SCRENON / SCREENOFF  in Android )

Comment: If you are looking for a swift solution without any Objective-C / Bridging header: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42509825/4177109

Answer (score 5):

I create same think using following.

You need to use the bridge for objective c code use into swift.

[Here is the Link for create the bridge between the Objective c to Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Once Completed then you can add following .h file into `yourproject-Bridging-Header`. file add the yourcontroller.h

Then add NotificationCenter.framework into your project.

Into your CustomObject.m

```
#import "notify.h"

-(void)registerAppforDetectLockState {

    int notify_token;
    notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", &notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token) {

        uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;
        notify_get_state(token, &state);

        if(state == 0) {
            NSLog(@"unlock device");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"lock device");
        }

        NSLog(@"com.apple.springboard.lockstate = %llu", state);
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
        [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello world!! I come becoz you lock/unlock your device :)"];
        notification.alertAction = @"View";
        notification.alertAction = @"Yes";
        [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    });
}
```

Then CustomObject.h

```
-(void)registerAppforDetectLockState;
```

Now into swift code you can directly use this method.

```
var instanceOfCustomObject: LockViewController = LockViewController()
instanceOfCustomObject.registerAppforDetectLockState();
```

May this helps lot.

Comment: thanks @Nimit Parekh , I was able to make the logs work , The new question is how can we do something when we detect a log using swift code ? :)

Comment: Usage of this private string is now causing rejections, need to think of an alternative.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman now do you having any alternate way please mentation here because above answer now not able to work longer.

Comment: You could replace with detecting going to the background. `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` background and screenlock are slightly correlated