# Check device is locked or unlocked

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, locked

I use the following code to check iphone lock state.

```
int notify_token;

notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", &notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token) {

    uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;
    notify_get_state(token, &state);

    if (state == 0)
    {
        // Locked
    }
    else
    {
        // Unlocked
    }
});
```

The problem is that we get notification only if device is locked or  unlocked. I want to know the current lock status. ie. I have started the app and at any point of time I want to know whether device is locked or unlocked. Using the above code we will be notified only when device is locked or unlocked by the user.

Is there any alternatives for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked using Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429800/how-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked-using-swift)

Answer (score 5):

Refer

```
static void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    // the "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification will always come after the "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" notification
    CFStringRef nameCFString = (CFStringRef)name;
    NSString *lockState = (NSString*)nameCFString;
    NSLog(@"Darwin notification NAME = %@",name);

    if([lockState isEqualToString:@"com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"])
    {
        NSLog(@"DEVICE LOCKED");
        //Logic to disable the GPS
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"LOCK STATUS CHANGED");
        //Logic to enable the GPS
    }
}

-(void)registerforDeviceLockNotif
{
    //Screen lock notifications
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                  CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

     CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.lockstate"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
}
```

Moreover you can set Global bool variable and set its value whether device is locked or not.

Comment: On iOS 10, I get ``lockcomplete`` before I get ``lockstate``. How is it possible to use this code to track if the phone is locked or unlocked? Did this change with iOS 10?

Comment: This usage is now being rejected.

Comment: where to call this method and what parameter should be pass?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman is their any other way to implement lock unlock state in ios and apple allow us to publish those app.

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
/**
 Start listen "Device Locked" notifications
 */
func registerforDeviceLockNotif() {
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                nil,
                                {(center: CFNotificationCenter!, observer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, name: CFString!, object: UnsafePointer<Void>, userInfo: CFDictionary!) -> Void in
                                    // the "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification will always come after the "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" notification
                                    let lockState = name as String
                                    if lockState == "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" {
                                        NSLog("DEVICE LOCKED");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        NSLog("LOCK STATUS CHANGED");
                                    }

        },
                                "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete",
                                nil,
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately)
}
```