# NSDate to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to detect if the `iOS` device is locked or unlocked using this method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31430517/6348190), so it is necessary for me to set an `NSDate` to `NSUserDefaults`.

When I am trying to get this `NSDate` by key - I get nil.

Setting `NSDate` to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *keyForLocking = @"deviceLocked";
NSDate *dateNow = [[NSDate alloc] init];

[defaults setObject:dateNow forKey:keyForLocking];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"date is %@", [defaults objectForKey:keyForLocking]);
```

Getting it:

```
NSDate *oldDate = (NSDate *) [defaults objectForKey:keyForLocking];
NSLog(@"oldDate is %@", oldDate);
```

In console I get:

```
ProjectName[649:107036] date is 2016-05-24 22:06:36 +0000
ProjectName[649:107036] oldDate is (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to update my NSLog with the key. And it's really common.

```
ProjectName[671:116804] oldDate is (null)
2016-05-25 01:58:03.601
ProjectName[671:116804] keyForLocking is deviceLocked
```

Comment: Please don't post your code or console output as an image. Please edit your question with the actual code and console output using copy and paste. (and *please* format it properly).

Comment: @rmaddy oh, I am sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: When do you call the "getting it" code? Are you sure that `keyForLocking` has the same value when getting the date as it had when setting the date?

Comment: I am calling it when device is unlocking. Yes, I am sure, this is a common variable

Comment: To be sure, update your `NSLog` statements to also log `keyForLocking` (and put it in quotes too). Update your question with the updated output.

Comment: @rmaddy Don't u know the solution of my problem?